# Я с большой буквы

Tags: нормы-языка

Нормативно ли написание слова я с большой буквы посреди предложения? Почему в русском не сложилось такой традиции написания, как, например, в английском?

Comment: Скромные мы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А это от менталитета народа зависит. На Западе на первое место ставят собственное "я" и пишут его с большой буквы как высшую ценность. А у нас с большой буквы пишут "Вы". Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: Германия тоже Запад, но ich (я) пишется со строчной. Хотя при переходе с английского на немецкий в первое мгновение очень хочется написать и ich с прописной ) + в немецком есть три меcтоимения sie, одно из которых, в значении нашего Вы, пишется с прописной, всегда.

Comment: А что скажут по этому поводу знатоки французского? Похоже, англичане в этом одиноки!

Comment: Зато англичане ко всем обращаются на "вы", пусть и со строчной )

Comment: Я не большой знаток французского, но там точно с загланой ничего не пишется без нужды. "Вы" как вежливая форма полностью совпадает со множственным числом и без контекста он него неотличима (что не совсем справедливо даже для английского: сравните yourself и youselves).  
Вот отношения между "ты" и "вы" у французов довольно  интересны. Даже супруги, не являющиеся друзьями с детства, обычно говорят друг другу "ты".

Comment: В английском звук "ай" (в любом слове) даже как-то с особой гордостью произносится, чуть ли не нараспев.

Comment: То бишь менталитет англичан вторгся в их язык. Нечто аналогичное вижу со словом "бог", которое должно писаться с прописной и которое в языки ввела религия. Кстати, во всех ли языках "бог" пишется с прописной?

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос "почему" некорректен изначально. На вопрос, зачем оно в английском, я еще бы рискнул ответить. В английском нет слов из одной буквы (не считая артикля), заглавная там - для зрительного выделения. Кстати говоря, английской орфографии такие вещи вообще свойственны. "Серьёзные" примеры здесь обсуждать не буду, ограничусь упоминанием того, что в "олбанской" версии английского you are, например, обычно передаются как "U R" - и тоже обычно через заглавные.

Что же касается русского, то понятно, никаких обоснований нормативности заглавного "Я" нет и быть не может. Окказиональные образования типа "Человек с большой буквы Я" либо несут другой смысл, либо так и остаются именно ненормативным окказионализмами.

Comment: В русском тоже нет слов из одной букву, кроме я и предлогов, поэтому аналогия с английским не верна.

Comment: Слово "и" - не предлог, это союз. Но все равно, конечно, служебное слово.

Comment: 2Валентин. Слово "аналогия" не верно. У меня не аналогия, а противопоставление. А по сути, да в русском есть массо предлогов и союз. В английском - одно единственное слово, артикль.

Answer (score 1):

До XI века "я" по-английски было ic, а в немецком ich. Оба эти местоимения берут свои корни из индоевропейского языка.

В XII-XV вв. местоимение ic претерпело множество изменений. Сначала оно превратилось в ich, а затем -ch отпало, и осталась лишь одна буква i. Она произносилась как [i:], а позже стала дифтонгом Ай.

Почему же это местоимение стали писать с большой буквы?

В средние века при печати текстов выделить это важное местоимение - i - было сложно: оно было незаметно, сливалось с другими словами.
Именно поэтому его стали выделять заглавной буквой, что сохранилось и по сей день.

Answer (score 0):

Михаил Задорнов  тоже  эксплутировал  тему  связи  менталитета  и  грамматики.  Юмористу  это  простительно.  А  атеисты  тоже  должны  писать  слово "бог"  с  прописной ?

Comment: Да, статья  в  НиЖ  интересная,  но  в  достаточной  степени  субъективная.  Нужно  достаточно  много  языков  исследовать  в  интересующем  нас  аспекте.  Это - раз.  И  менталитет  и  граматика  способны  изменяться  во  времени.  И  не  обязательно  с  одинаковой  скоростью. Это - два.  Да  и  изменяются  они  по  разным  законам.  Это  -  три.

Comment: Согласен  с  inna !

Answer (score 0):

Да, здесь всё дело в историческом укладе языка, который в свою очередь отражает национальное самосознание. Русские вообще редко "якают", предпочитая выражаться безличными предложениями (мне не спится, мне удалось), у англичан же везде в этих случаях гордое и звонко-звучное "Я". На эту тему хорошо написано вот в этой статье журнала "Наука и жизнь".
http://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/20386/

Comment: Есть очень важный момент: английский - язык аналитический, глаголы почти не имеют показателей лица (кроме 3 лица единственного числа: he/she/it does). Поэтому почти всегда обязательно наличие и подлежащего, и сказуемого. В синтетических языках (русский, итальянский) глаголы спрягаются по лицам и числам, поэтому подлежащее часто можно опустить, в том числе можно легко обходиться от местоимений. Так что, возможно, не такие уж носители английского и эгоцентричные, просто у них ограниченные средства выражения категории лица, и они просто вынуждены постоянно "айкать".

Answer (score 0):

[Я с большой буквы](https://youtu.be/2OuVmTP2aoE?t=55)

Гораздо важнее другое : в интернете многие пишут свои имена и фамилии с маленьких букв. Да еще не знают, как употребляется мягкий знак, например.

Себя надо уважать.

Comment: У вас сарказм насчет мягкого знака?